# Telerik RadEditor Add Snippets to Include JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to add some JavaScript to a `Telerik` `RadEditor` Snippets. The following code adds it to the `RadEditor` and works.

When I run it and add the snippet to the `RadEditor`, it adds it. When I inspect the Video, the HTML elements shows the  and below that the JavaScript code I added with snippet as well.

```
if (indVideoLink != null)
{
    RadEditor1.Snippets.Add("VideoLink",
    "<video id=\"azuremediaplayer\" class=\"azuremediaplayer amp - default- skin amp - big - play - centered\" tabindex=\"0\"></video>\"" +
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var myOptions = {\"nativeControlsForTouch\": false,controls: true,autoplay: true,width: \"640\",height: \"400\",}" +
    "myPlayer = amp(\"azuremediaplayer\", myOptions);myPlayer.src([{\"src\":" + 
    "\"" + indVideoLink + "\",\"type\":  \"appication/vnd.ms.sstr+xml" + 
    "}]);" +
    "</script>");
}

<telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" Runat="server" Content='<%# Bind("InductionNotes") %>' 
ToolsFile="~/intranet/OHS/Tools.xml"  Width="800px" Height="400px" ContentAreaCssFile="~/Intranet/OHS/ContentEditor.css" OnLoad="RadEditor1_Load">
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

But then I save it to InductionNotes using a Command Button and it only saves the 
`<video></video>` and its contents. How do I get the `RadEditor' to save the JavaScript?

The `Tools.xml` file contains the following in Snippet

```
<tool name="InsertSnippet"/>
</tools>
```

I thought I might have add something to the `Tools.xml` file but I am not sure.

I should add that the RadGrid is in a `DetailsView` and everthing else is saving and working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is this line of code which disables the RemoveScripts filter which is enabled by default.

```
RadEditor1.DisableFilter(Telerik.Web.UI.EditorFilters.RemoveScripts);
```